# Losing messages between threads

Tags: android, multithreading, opencv, classification, face-detection

I am programming in Android environment, and I have a main thread and a worker thread.

The main thread captures frames (saving every single frame into a Mat object) from a video stream, opened with org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView, and sends it with its timestamp to the worker thread. The worker thread should be able to receive it and process it with some techniques.

I have found that, if I use a cascade classifier in the worker thread, for face detection, some messages received from the main thread are lost. I have discovered this with the timestamp, which is a sort of index for mat.

If I don't use cascade classifier (its "detectMultiScale" method), the sequence of the received mats is: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7...
If I use cascade classifier, I receive only: 1,3,5,9 etc. Some messages are lost.
Why this? How can I solve?

The thread which send message:

```
        Message m=Message.obtain();
        m.what=123;
        m.obj=resultedFrame;
        myAsynkTask.mHandler.sendMessage(m);
```

The thread which receive:

```
  while(running){
            synchronized (this) {
                Looper.prepare();
                mHandler = new Handler(){
                    public void handleMessage( Message msg ){
                        if(msg.what==123){
                            str.setmRgba(((structureMat)msg.obj).getmRgba());
                            str.setTimestamp(((structureMat)msg.obj).getTimestamp());
                            if((str.getmRgba())!=null) {
                                set_finalMat(str.getmRgba());
                                //Simple Face Detection with a cascade classifier.
                                faceFound = seg_asynk.findFaceMat(finalMatScaled, frameGrayAsynk, feat_asynk);
                           }

                        }
                    }
                };
                Looper.loop();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You are most likely to get help if you [post your code](http://sscce.org).

Comment: I've edited the question, adding some pieces of code.